# How to find the most relevant rows using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have a MySQL table of articles with several thousands of rows. Each article row can have up to 3 VARCHAR tag fields: `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`, each of which can be empty (filled with `NA` in the database)

The `article` table schema is like this:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| body       | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                           |
| visits     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 1                 |                |
| slug       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| lasthit    | datetime     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| tag1       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NA                |                |
| tag2       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NA                |                |
| tag3       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NA                |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I'd like to find a list of `10 Relevant Articles` for each article, so the rows which have higher number similar tags with that article should come first. So for example, if ArticleA has:

```
tag1 = "cat"
tag2 = "dog"
tag3 = "fish"
```

The query should return 10 articles which have the very same tags, and if there are only 4 row having these 3 tags,the remaining results must be from rows have 2 common tags, and if there are not enough rows with 2 matching tags, 1 matching tag should be returned.

I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Which mysql version?

Comment: The mysql version is 5.7

Comment: Show table structure, sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Jens I added the schema. The whole data is too long to be shown here.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), alarm bells should start ringing. Consider whether your schema design is optimal

Comment: @Strawberry, while your point is valid, I have inherited the database and have not luxury to redesign it.

Comment: I would argue that it's a necessity, not a luxury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So newA.* is a list of 10 articles with some match. The depends on the input of a previous articleID for articleA.

```
SELECT newA.*
FROM articles articleA
JOIN articles newA
  ON newA.tag1 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3) OR
     newA.tag2 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3) OR
     newA.tag3 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3)
WHERE articleA.id = {some explict number}
   AND newA.id != articleA.id
ORDER BY
  (newA.tag1 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3) IS NOT NULL) +
  (newA.tag2 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3) IS NOT NULL) +
  (newA.tag3 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3) IS NOT NULL)
  DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The `ORDER BY` takes each tag, and `X IN (...)` is either:

- 1 - true, value exists
- 0 - false, value didn't exist
- NULL - newA.tagX was null.

The 'IS NOT NULL' turns NULL into 0, so it can be added.

This query is rather inefficient as it requires to scan the entire articles to determine a match.

To be more efficient a `article_tags` table that maps the `id` to a `tag` that has a `id,tag` primary key would result in this query:

```
SELECT newA.*
FROM articles articleA
  JOIN article_tags tagsA ON articleA.id=tagsA.id
  JOIN article_tags newAtags ON tagsA.tag=newA.tag
  JOIN articles newA ON newAtags.id=newA.id
WHERE articleA.id = {some explicit number}
   AND newA.id != articleA.id
GROUP BY newA.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I get this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+
  newA.tag2 IN (articleA.tag1, articleA.tag2, articleA.tag3) +
  newA.tag3 I' at line 10`

Comment: [corrected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=22c3bf791f89d3f2e8eac5198344ff81). PS. including `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the table structure makes it easier to produce tests, and show the indexes if you ever ask a performance question. Welcome to SO. Probably consider dba.stackexchange.com/ for purely SQL questions next time.

Comment: Thanks, actually I used `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. The error is gone, but now I see the query is not very effective. Can you explain how does it work when two rows have similar  tags `cat` and `dog` but on different columns, or there are some rows with empty tags?

Comment: looks like `DESCRIBE {table}`. You are right, its not very effective. The lookup of articleA is easy but to get the rest, the entire table must be scanned.  If `cat` is in `newA.tag3`, a potential new article, it checks if that is in the list either of the of tags of `articleA`. Empty tags should be `NULL` to make this work (except for the order which I'll fix now). Otherwise you have messy things to say `!='NA'` extending the `JOIN ON..` criteria.