# How to exclude certain strings from join

Tags: mysql, sql, search

Using mysql 5.7, I'd like to query `article` table for rows which have the most similar `tag` columns:

```
 CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `slug` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lasthit` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `tag1` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA',
  `tag2` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA',
  `tag3` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10800 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT newA.title, newA.slug, newA.tag1, newA.tag2, newA.tag3
        FROM article a
        JOIN article newA
          ON newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) OR
             newA.tag2 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) OR
             newA.tag3 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3)
        WHERE a.id = 242 
           AND newA.id != a.id
        ORDER BY
          (newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) IS NOT NULL) +
          (newA.tag2 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) IS NOT NULL) +
          (newA.tag3 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) IS NOT NULL)
          DESC
        LIMIT 10;
```

I'd like to exclude results where the tag length is less than 2 characters, so that irrelevant items (where the tag column is empty or just has `NA` in it do not sneak in.

What I did is to add `AND LEN(a.tag1)>2 AND LEN(a.tag2)>2 AND LEN(a.tag3)>2` to `WHERE` clause, but then I get lots of `Display all 1333 possibilities? (y or n)` instead of results.

I have also tried

```
  ...
      ON (newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) OR
         newA.tag2 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) OR
         newA.tag3 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3)) AND
        (LEN(a.tag1)>2 AND LEN(a.tag2)>2 AND LEN(a.tag3)>2)        
  ...
```

But then I get

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION myawsomedb.LEN does not exist
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: _which have the most similar_ Thats not a very specific criteria. Can you qualify that to something specific

Comment: This is the follow up of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825512/how-to-find-the-most-relevant-rows-using-mysql where I explained my goal in more details.

Comment: Adding `AND` conditions to the `WHERE` clause can only reduce the number of rows selected, it can't increase it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's what the `ORDER BY` does -- it adds up the number of tags that matched.

Comment: `AND newA.id != a.id` should be in the `ON` clause, since it relates the two tables. Make sure you use parentheses when combining `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: @Barmar, right, I want to limit results, to exclude cases where rows are picked just because the similarity comes from the tag being empty or `NA`.

Comment: @Barmar I added the `LEN` to `ON` part and added parentheses arount `OR` and `AND`, as you can see in the updated question. But still get error.

Comment: MySQL don't know LEN() - it knows LENGTH().

Comment: That message about possibilities isn't coming from executing the query, it's because lots of things begin with `len` and the interactive environment is asking what you want to use there.

Comment: @Akina, replacing `LEN` with `LENGTH` resolves the error. Thanks for the tip. But still results with empty tags are bing returned. So the query is faulty.

Comment: On a side note: `newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3) IS NOT NULL`? `newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3)` can never be NULL; it's either TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LENGTH() > 2` combined with your existing criteria and appropriate parentheses:

```
SELECT newA.title, newA.slug, newA.tag1, newA.tag2, newA.tag3
FROM article a
JOIN article newA
  ON newA.id > a.id
  AND
  (
       (LENGTH(newA.tag1) > 2 AND newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3))
    OR (LENGTH(newA.tag2) > 2 AND newA.tag2 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3))
    OR (LENGTH(newA.tag3) > 2 AND newA.tag3 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3))
  )
WHERE a.id = 242
ORDER BY
  (LENGTH(newA.tag1) > 2 AND newA.tag1 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3)) +
  (LENGTH(newA.tag2) > 2 AND newA.tag2 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3)) +
  (LENGTH(newA.tag3) > 2 AND newA.tag3 IN (a.tag1, a.tag2, a.tag3))
  DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

(I made this `newA.id > a.id`, because I expect a "new" ID to be greater than the old one. Change this back to `newA.id <> a.id` in case I am wrong.)